# Using Nuxt 3 built-in composables inside typescript files with SSR enabled

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I've fully developed an application using Nuxt 3 and Vuetify 3 with the SSR flag switched to false. Based on the changes in the requirements, now I need to provide support for an SSR build. After setting the SSR flag to true, I get the error indicating that I can't use composables such as useRouter and useCookie inside typescript files. This is because I've implemented a multi layer structure to handle API calls and configurations.
Here's an example of my base fetch service:

```js
class FetchService {
    static async get(url: string, query?: object, headers?: object) {
        let fetchOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            query, headers
        };
        return await this.createRequest(url, fetchOptions);
    }

    static async post(url: string, body: object = {}, query?: object, headers?: object) {
        let fetchOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body, query, headers
        };
        return await this.createRequest(url, fetchOptions);
    }

    static async put(url: string, body: object = {}, query?: object, headers?: object) {
        let fetchOptions = {
            method: 'PUT',
            body, query, headers
        };
        return await this.createRequest(url, fetchOptions);
    }

    static async delete(url: string, body: object = {}, query?: object, headers?: object) {
        let fetchOptions = {
            method: 'DELETE',
            body, query, headers
        };
        return await this.createRequest(url, fetchOptions);
    }

    static async createRequest(url: string, payload: any) {
        return useFetch(url, {
            baseURL: BACKEND_URL,
            ...payload,
            async onRequest({ request, options }) {
                options.headers = options.headers || {}
                options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
                const locale = StorageService.getItem('locale');
                if (locale && locale === 'fa') {
                    options.headers['Accept-Language'] = 'fa-IR';
                } else {
                    options.headers['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US';
                }
                if (getAccessToken() !== null) {
                    options.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`;
                }
            },
            async onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
                const router = useRouter();
                const route = useRoute();
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    if (getAccessToken() !== null && getRefreshToken() !== null) {
                        deleteAccessToken();
                        let {data, error} = await FetchService.post('/auth/refresh/', {refresh: getRefreshToken()});
                        if (error.value && error.value?.statusCode === 401) {
                            deleteRefreshToken();
                            if (route.path !== '/auth') {
                                router.push(`/auth?redirect=${route.path}`);
                            }
                        }
                        if (data.value) {
                            setAccessToken(data.value.access);
                            setRefreshToken(data.value.refresh);
                            return await FetchService.createRequest(url, payload);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (route.path !== '/auth') {
                            router.push(`/auth?redirect=${route.path}`);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.error(response._data.errors[0].detail)
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

export default FetchService;
```

And I've implemented different services based on their use case that extends this class like the following:

```js
import FetchService from "~/services/fetchService";

class AuthService extends FetchService {
    static async login(data: any) {
        return await this.post('/auth/login/', data);
    }

    static async otp(data: any) {
        return await this.post('/auth/login/verify_otp/', data);
    }

    static async refresh(data: any) {
        return await this.post('/auth/refresh/', data);
    }
}

export default AuthService;
```

And then I simply use the services inside my components:

```js
const {data, pending, error} = await AuthService.login(model);
```

The implemented solution works perfectly in SPA mode, but with SSR enabled, the app fails to function properly. Based on what I've found out so far, I need to refactor a large portion of the application by moving all the content inside typescript files to Vue components in order to bypass the errors and I'm looking for a solution or workaround to keep the amount of refactoring to a minimum, maybe a method to keep the current structure without having to rewrite the logic in Vue components?!